# Split number and put each digit to separate html element

Tags: jquery, loops, split

The problem is that I do not know how to break the loop for the first number and start again for the next one. Currently, one **span.nNumber** has a total digits of the two numbers (123456) and the next **span.nNumber** contains digits only from another number (456).
Goal is to create sequence 123 and 456:

**Markup**:

```
<span class='nNumber'>
 <span>1</span>
 <span>2</span>
 <span>3</span>
</span> 

<span class='nNumber'>
 <span>4</span>
 <span>5</span>
 <span>6</span>
</span>
```

JavaScript (**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/PZ8Pt/2/)**):

```
$('div .number').each(function(){
    var number = $(this).text();
    var i = 0;

    $(this).parent().prepend($("<span class='nNumber'></span>"));
    while(i<number.length)
    {
        $(this).closest('span').hide();
        var nChar = number.charAt(i);  
        i++;
        $('.nNumber').append('<span class="digit-'+nChar+'">'+nChar.split(" ").join(", ")+'</span>');
    }
});​
```

Comment: You want to create a span for each number between 123 and 456?

Comment: <span class='nNumber'><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span></span> and <span class='nNumber'><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span></span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `while` loop, use the following;

```
$(this).parent().find('.nNumber').append('<span class="digit-'+nChar+'">'+nChar+'</span>');
```

This way, you'll always modify the `nNumber` class inside the `div` you are iterating over. If you use `$(".nNumber")` you'll get *all* elements whose class is `nNumber`, even the ones that are not in your current `div`. That's why the second iteration of `.each()` adds the extra digits `456` to the first `span`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E5HhN/)**.